# Javascript Closures with doesn't work with returned function

Tags: javascript, closures, this

I read the [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) question and thought i finally understood closures.

Especially this point is very confusing right now:

> Example 7
>
> This final example shows that each call creates a separate closure for the local variables. There is not a single closure per function declaration. There is a closure for each call to a function.
> ..........................................

Ok, so Example 7 shows this example:

```
function newClosure(someNum, someRef) {
    // Local variables that end up within closure
    var num = someNum;
    var anArray = [1,2,3];
    var ref = someRef;
    return function(x) {
        num += x;
        anArray.push(num);
        document.write('num: ' + num +
            '; anArray: ' + anArray.toString() +
            '; ref.someVar: ' + ref.someVar + "<br>");
      }
}
obj = {someVar: 4};
fn1 = newClosure(4, obj);
fn2 = newClosure(5, obj);
fn1(1); // num: 5; anArray: 1,2,3,5; ref.someVar: 4;
fn2(1); // num: 6; anArray: 1,2,3,6; ref.someVar: 4;
obj.someVar++;
fn1(2); // num: 7; anArray: 1,2,3,5,7; ref.someVar: 5;
fn2(2); // num: 8; anArray: 1,2,3,6,8; ref.someVar: 5;
```

This example works for me as it should.

So I experiemented a little and i don't really understand why this code doesn't work (looks like it doesn't even create a new closure on function call)

```
function createCounter(startValue){

    var localCounter;

    this.setCounter = function(firstValue) {
       localCounter = firstValue; 
    }
 
    this.getValue = function(){return localCounter;};
    this.increment = function(){localCounter++;};
    this.setCounter(startValue);

    return this;
}

var Counter1 = createCounter(1);
document.write(Counter1.getValue()); //1
Counter1.increment();
var Counter1Value = Counter1.getValue(); // 2
var Counter0 =  createCounter(0); //works as it should if i put a "new createCounter(0) here, but why?
document.write("<br >Counter 1 oldValue:" + Counter1Value); //2
document.write("<br >Counter 1 currentValue:" + Counter1.getValue()); //0 (why is the localvariable overwritten?)
document.write("<br >Counter 0 currentValue:" + Counter0.getValue()); // //0
```

why do i need to add the "new" keyword to create a second closure, and why are both Counter1 and Counter0 using the same localCounter variable?

Comment: This has more to do with `new` than closures. I would suggest reading up on how `this` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As elclanrs says, it is all about `this`:

When you call `createCounter(1)`, `this` is unchanged, most likely remaining the global scope. Given `document.write`, it's safe to say the global scope is `window`. So, you create `window.setCounter` as a function that will set `localCounter`, a variable hidden in a closure, and `window.getValue` to a function that reads this hidden variable; it initialises `localCounter` to `1`; it then returns `window` and assigns it to `Counter1`.

Then, `Counter1.getValue()` calls `window.getValue()`, which returns `1`. All good. Same with `increment`.

However, since you are operating on the global context all the time, when you do `createCounter(0)`, you are *overwriting* `window.getValue` (and other functions) with a *new* closure that now references a *different* hidden `localCounter`, this one initialised to `0`. Since both `Counter0` and `Counter1` point at the *same* object (namely, `window`), it is not too farfetched that `Counter1.getValue()` and `Counter0.getValue()` should also return the same thing (given that they both have no side-effects).

This changes drastically with the `new` keyword, which is one of the several ways in JavaScript to change what `this` is. If you do `var Counter1 = new createCounter(1)` and `var Counter0 = new createCounter(0)`, `this` inside the function is a new object in both cases; and `Counter1` has different closures on it than `Counter0`.

Specifically, `new createCounter(0)` will do something like this pseudocode:

```
var oldThis = this;  // save current context
this = {};           // make a new object
createCounter(0);    // initialize the new object
this = oldThis;      // restore current context
```

so you can see why the values are kept distinct.

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation really helped me out.

Comment: One more tiny thing: by convention, functions that are meant to be constructors (i.e. those that should make new objects and be called with `new`) are named with `TitleCase` noun phrases (thus, `Counter`). Other variables are in `camelCase` (thus, `counter0`, `counter1`, `setCounter`...). (Except for variables that are pretending to be constants, which are in `UPPER_CASE`). Conventions make the code more readable to everyone involved.